# Sorting error with google-docs-api indices must be integer

Tags: python, google-docs-api

This is quite a long question and I may miss something out, so if more information is needed ask.

Iv been scraping data from google scholar using scaperwiki and up till recently I was just giving putting all the urls in like this.

```
elec_urls = """http://1.hidemyass.com/ip-5/encoded/Oi8vc2Nob2xhci5nb29nbGUuY29tL2NpdGF0aW9ucz91c2VyPWo0YnRpeXNBQUFBSiZobD1lbg%3D%3D&f=norefer
http://4.hidemyass.com/ip-1/encoded/Oi8vc2Nob2xhci5nb29nbGUuY29tL2NpdGF0aW9ucz91c2VyPVZXaFJiZEFBQUFBSiZobD1lbg%3D%3D&f=norefer
http://4.hidemyass.com/ip-2/encoded/Oi8vc2Nob2xhci5nb29nbGUuY29tL2NpdGF0aW9ucz91c2VyPV84X09JSWNBQUFBSiZobD1lbg%3D%3D&f=norefer
http://1.hidemyass.com/ip-4/encoded/Oi8vc2Nob2xhci5nb29nbGUuY29tL2NpdGF0aW9ucz91c2VyPUh3WHdmTGtBQUFBSiZobD1lbg%3D%3D&f=norefer
http://4.hidemyass.com/ip-1/encoded/Oi8vc2Nob2xhci5nb29nbGUuY29tL2NpdGF0aW9ucz91c2VyPXU1NWFWZEFBQUFBSiZobD1lbg%3D%3D&f=norefer
""".strip()

elec_urls = elec_urls.splitlines()
```

I then scrape each page and put the information I want in a list of dicts, sort it once, remove the duplicates and then sort it again using a different key, I then export information I want to a google docs spreadsheet. This works 100%.

I have tried to change it so that I can have another Google docs spreadsheet and from here I can put all the urls in and it will do the same thing. Below is what I have done so far.

```
def InputUrls(Entered_doc, EnteredURL):
    username = 'myemail'
    password = 'mypassword'
    doc_name = Entered_doc
    spreadsheet_id = Entered_doc
    worksheet_id = 'od6'

    # Connect to Google
    gd_client = gdata.spreadsheet.service.SpreadsheetsService()
    gd_client.email = username 
    gd_client.password = password  
    gd_client.source = EnteredURL
    gd_client.ProgrammaticLogin()

    #Now that we're connected, we query the spreadsheet by name, and extract the unique spreadsheet and worksheet IDs.

    rows = gd_client.GetListFeed(spreadsheet_id, worksheet_id).entry
    #At this point, you have a row iterator which will yield rows for the spreadsheet. This example will print everything out, keyed by column names:
    urlslist = []
    for row in rows:
        for key in row.custom:
            urlslist.append(row.custom[key].text)
        return urlslist

def URLStoScrape(ToScrape):
    Dep = []
    for i in range(0,len(ToScrape)):
        Department_urls = ToScrape[i].strip()
        Department_urls = Department_urls.splitlines() 
        Done = MainScraper(Department_urls)
        Dep.append(Done)
    
return Dep

ElectricalDoc = '0AkGb10ekJtfQdG9EOHN0VzRDdVhWaG1kNVEtdVpyRlE'
ElectricalUrl = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?    '
ToScrape_Elec = InputUrls(ElectricalDoc, ElectricalUrl)
```

This seems to scrape fine but then when the program goes to sort I get the below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./code/scraper", line 230, in <module>
    Total_and_Hindex_Electrical = GetTotalCitations(Electrical)
  File "./code/scraper", line 89, in GetTotalCitations
    Wrt_CitationURL = Sorting(Department, "CitationURL")
  File "./code/scraper", line 15, in Sorting
    SortedData = sorted(Unsorted, reverse = True, key = lambda k: k[pivot])
  File "./code/scraper", line 15, in <lambda>
    SortedData = sorted(Unsorted, reverse = True, key = lambda k: k[pivot])
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

I think, almost sure, that it has something to do with the URLStoScrape function, but i don't know how to fix it, any help would be great.

Thanks let me know if more info in needed

Comment: It looks like the pivot variable is a string instead of being an integer. Could you post the code for sorted()?

Comment: Here is the code for the sorting function. 

def Sorting(Unsorted, pivot): 
    SortedData = sorted(Unsorted, reverse = True, key = lambdak:k[pivot])
    return SortedData

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the line 89,

```
GetTotalCitations Wrt_CitationURL = Sorting(Department, "CitationURL")
```

Either "CitationUrl" should be an integer index, or the value of value passed to the
`key` function in the `sorted()` should be a dictionary.

Comment: Maybe but that didn't seem to make a difference when I was doing it the other way, any idea why that might be?

Comment: This might help when I print the the output of URLStoScrape i get something that looks like this [[This is empty] [{}{}{}{}{}{}{}]]. everything enclosed in {} has the data inside. But when I print the equivulent when I just have all the URLs listed, I get something like this [{}{}{}{}{}{}]. Could it be the extra list and the empty list causing the problem?

Comment: Perhaps the sorting function does not take into account empty results?

Comment: Thats probably it. Why its returning an empty result i do not know